# How can I calculate the required date in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need to check if today's date < 20 then set result var as 1st of next month.
If today's date > 20 then set result var as 1st of next month following the next month ?

Example:

- for `24-09-2015` set result to `1st Nov 2015`
- for `19-09-2015` set result to `1st Oct 2015`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, it's a perfectly legitimate (and somewhat difficult) question.  The poor wording is likely a language barrier issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a bit tricky because of the date arithmetic:

```
set @var = (case when day(getdate()) < 20
                 then cast(dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) as date)
                 else cast(dateadd(month, 2, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) as date)
            end);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2676) is a SQL Fiddle that shows the calculation.

Comment: Thank you.exactly What I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '20150924'
SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(@d) < 20 
            THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@d) + 1, @d)) 
            ELSE DATEADD(mm, 2, DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@d) + 1, @d)) END;
```